# How can I access a specific object in an ArrayList once certain objects in it are deleted?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of Objects (let's call them SampleObjects), and then I delete some random ones. Here is some simplified code to illustrate what I mean:

```
ArrayList<SampleObject> sample = new ArrayList<SampleObject>();
sample.add(new SampleObject); //call this object A, current index 0
sample.add(new SampleObject); //call this object B, current index 1
sample.add(new SampleObject); //call this object C, current index 2
```

If I delete object B by
    sample.remove(1);

Which causes object C to have index 1 right now. How can I then refer to object C specifically later on? If I have a large ArrayList, the only solution I could think of is to make an array which tracks the current index in the sample ArrayList. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Use a Map instead if you want to access your object by some key.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are looking for a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Then you can retrieve items by a certain key.

Updated from comments, user: @DwB

> The key of the map can be an Integer, so you could refer to A by "0",
>   B by "1", and C by "2". C would still be "2" after deleting element B

Hope it helps.

Comment: the key of the map can be an Integer, so you could refer to A by "0", B by "1", and C by "2".  C would still be "2" after deleting element B.